# Oracle - Group by the most frequent entries

Tags: oracle

I have 2 tables on my Oracle DB

One with a product list

```
PRODUCT_ID - PRODUCT_NAME - PRODUCT_PRICE
     1            P_1            50
     2            P_2            60
     3            P_3            70
     4            P_4            80
```

And one with the orders

```
   CLIENT_ID - PRODUCT_ID   -  ORDER_PRICE
         1            1          50
         2            3          60
         3            2          70
         4            2          70
```

I need to make a query so it returns the product_list table but ordered by the most frequent Product_id in the orders table. So in this case the Product ID=2 must be first on the list.

I have found some examples but i cant find something that will work for this case.

Comment: Are you using _both_ MySQL and Oracle?  If not, please remove one of the tags.  (Yeah, MySQL is owned by Oracle, but use only [mysql] for that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use subquery for aggregation on orders table to find count for each product id and then left join it with the product_list table to use the calculated count for ordering.

```
select p.*
from product_list p
left join (
    select product_id,
        count(*) as cnt
    from orders
    group by product_id
    ) o on p.product_id = o.product_id
order by o.cnt desc nulls last;
```

Answer (score 1):

- LEFT Join is used since not all products could have orders and we need to find the count of orders for each product.
- GROUP BY is used because we use the aggregate count() to find the occurrence of orders for a given Product.
- ORDER BY DESC is used so the count is ordered highest count of product orders first to lowest. However when ties exist, we don't know what order will be returned as a second level of order by is not defined. Could be order  We could add a Product_ID so they are low to high after that...

.

```
SELECT PL.Product_ID, PL.Product_Name, PL.Product_Price, count(O.Product_ID) cnt  
FROM Product_List 
LEFT JOIN Orders O 
  on O.Product_ID = PL.Product_ID 
GROUP BY PL.Product_ID, PL.Product_Name, PL.Product_Price 
ORDER BY cnt Desc
```